# Shutdown/Reboot (occasionally) freezes

Tags: 11.10, freeze, shutdown

My computer would occasionally freeze when I shutdown or rebooted the computer for whatever reason. As of late, every time I shutdown or restart it freezes and now it's becoming a PITA.

I have no idea how to debug this and really need some help :(.

Comment: duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66108/shutdown-stuck-at-ubuntu-logo

Comment: maybe you could do as @waltinator said, then edit your entry a show the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were debugging this, I would cause the event (freeze when shutdown/reboot), boot into a recovery mode (do the least recovery possible), and do an `ls -lrt /var/log`. This would tell me which log files have been modified recently. Any messages having to do with the problem would be in these files.